# Get all items inside multiple select in flask-python

Tags: python, html, flask

How can I get all the items inside select-multiple in flask-python, not just the selected items.

```
<select name='tests' class=" form-control" multiple>
      <option value="Test1">Test1</option>
      <option value="Test2">Test2</option>
      <option value="Test3">Test3</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getlist`

```
tests = request.form.getlist('tests')
```

Comment: yes i know that, but i want to get all the items inside the select-multiple not just the selected(highlighted) value.

Comment: @marlonpd oh... In that case can you try to post from javascript. I know `form.serialize` will dump all the select inside. And let me know